# Getting text to speech to write a . (period)

Tags: voice-recognition

I have just started to use Googles speech to text on my Sony Xperia Z3+ and it is very precise, both in English and Danish. But I cannot get it to write any punctuation in either language.

A period would be just fine, but if I dictate in English and say "period", it writes the word "period". I have also tried "dot" and in Danish "punktum". There is a settings button, but no option to fix this.

The funny thing is, that if I pause, it will capitalize correctly, like there were a . but I still have to add them afterwards.

The most frustrating part is, that when I search for solutions, the solution is to say "period" or replies to people who want to have the literal word written.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is your inflection, that is, the rise and fall of tonal character. Saying the word "period" works for me.

I say "PEER-Ee-uhd", falling in tone as I say the word.